# Podio WebHooks RequestBin Testing

Tags: podio

I want to test Podio Web Hooks (item.update) through RequestBin. I have created WebHook and it shows in my account. When I created i got one request for Verify on RequestBin URL. But in Podio it is showing as Inactive.

Kindly let me know how can I test further.

Answer (score 4):

You have to `validate` the hook using the code received from the verify call. The hook will become active only after on successful validation.

Refer Podio documentation on how to Validate hook here, [Validate Podio hook verification](https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/validate-hook-verification-215241)

Comment: They also provide a nice [tutorial](https://developers.podio.com/examples/webhooks).

Answer (score 0):

So the webhook content is pretty bare bones, it just has request parameters for a variable or two in addition to any URL parameters you are passing based on your webhook URI. There is a whole description of what the parameters provided are here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/hookshttps://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks

Basically whatever is catching your webhook will need to be able to connect to the Podio API and fetch the item with the ID passed in the webhook.